# Encryption with XOR in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, xor

I have a bit of Python code that I made. It's using XOR to encrypt. I don't really have much knowledge of Xor so could someone tell me why this code does absolutely nothing, or could at least point me to somewhere a complete newbie could learn XOR? Thanks!

```
def xor_attmpt():
    message = input("Enter message to be ciphered: ")
    cipher = []
    for i in message:
        cipher.append(bin(ord(i))[2::])

    cipher = "".join(cipher)
    privKey = input("Enter the private key: ")
    keydecrypt = []
    for j in privKey:
        keydecrypt.append(bin(ord(j))[2::])
    keydecrypt = "".join(keydecrypt )

    print("key is '{0}'" .format(keydecrypt))
    print("encrypted text is '{0}'" .format(cipher))
    from operator import xor
    for letter in message:
        print(xor(bool(cipher)), bool(keydecrypt))
```

Comment: Uh, what do you mean "does absolutely nothing"?

Comment: You don't actually call the function in the example you've posted, so nothing will run. Do you have a `xor_attmpt()` call somewhere later on?

Comment: Having `print(xor(bool(cipher)), bool(keydecrypt))` as the body of the loop makes little sense. For one thing, when you iterate over `message`, neither `cipher` nor `keydecrypt` ever change, so you will be printing exactly the same thing again and again.

Comment: @JohnColeman: For 1), see the `from operator import xor` line.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are needlessly converting between strings and `ints`. bitwise xor in python, `^`, is meant to work on *ints*

Comment: @user2357112 I see -- I overlooked the random import in the middle of a function definition. I thought OP had their own definition somewhere else and didn't want to assume that they had implemented it correctly.

Comment: In my Python 3.5 environment, this fails when **xor** gets only one argument.